# How to check if a url is a file or folder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, url, path

In javascript/jquery, given a string of a url, how can I check if it is a url to a file or a directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, because there's no difference in HTTP.

A URL is neither a "file" nor a "directory."  It's a *resource*.  When requesting that resource, the server responds with, well, a response.  That response consists of headers and content.

A header (such as `content-disposition`) may indicate that the response should be *treated* as a file by the consuming client.  But in and of itself it's not a "file" because HTTP is not a file system.

And any resource can return any response that the server wants.  For example, you might request `http://www.something.com` and expect not to get a file because you didn't ask for one.  But it can still return one.  Or, even if you ask for `index.html` you might not get a "file" called "index.html" but instead some other response.

Even if you ask for a "directory" from your point of view, the server is still responding with headers and content.  That content may take the form of a directory listing, but it's indistinguishable from any other successful response aside from parsing the content itself.

If you're looking for something which the server has indicated is a "file" then you're looking for the `content-disposition` header in the response and you'll want to parse out the value of that header.  Other than that one case, I'd suspect that whatever need you have to know if it's a "file" or a "directory" is a symptom of a design problem in whatever you're trying to do, since the question itself is moot in HTTP.

Answer (score 10):

Like David said, you can't really tell. But if you want to find out if the last part of a url has a '.' in it (maybe that's what you mean by a "file"?), this might work:

```
function isFile(pathname) {
    return pathname.split('/').pop().indexOf('.') > -1;
}

function isDir(pathname) { return !isFile(pathname); }

console.log(isFile(document.location.pathname));
```

Comment: This solution would only work if the URL is known to have file names at the end. It's not an absolute solution because of URL rewrites so a file can be `https://something.com/dl/file/1234`

Answer (score 4):

Just to update with a version that works with a string, you can use the built in [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) function in JavaScript (unless you are in <IE11). As those who have come before me have mentioned, it doesn't work in many cases, this is just a rough hack to check for a `.` in the filename of a string url.

```
const checkIfFile = (url) => {
  url = new URL(url);
  return url.pathname.split('/').pop().indexOf('.') > 0;
}

const urls = [
  "http://example.com",
  "http://example.com?v=1",
  "http://example.com/no",
  "http://example.com/no?no=3.1",
  "http://example.com/yes.jpg?yes=3.1",
  "http://example.com/yes.jpg",
  "http://example.com/maybe.someone.did.this/yes.jpg",
  "http://example.com/maybe.someone.did.this/",
];

urls.forEach(url => {
    console.log("The url " + url + " is " + (checkIfFile(url) ? "true" : "false"));
})
```

Outputs the following:

```
"The url http://example.com is false"
"The url http://example.com?v=1 is false"
"The url http://example.com/no is false"
"The url http://example.com/no?no=3.1 is false"
"The url http://example.com/yes.jpg?yes=3.1 is true"
"The url http://example.com/yes.jpg is true"
"The url http://example.com/maybe.someone.did.this/yes.jpg is true"
"The url http://example.com/maybe.someone.did.this/ is false"
```